# How does LEGO decide the color of internal set pieces?

Tags: design, colour

While building many LEGO sets I have noticed that for internal pieces you cannot see when the set is finished; LEGO often chooses mis-matching colors.  For instance in the (amazing) Saturn 5 set most of the pieces are of the white, black, gray family.  However there are some green/blue internal pieces.  Doesn't match the rocket at all.  I have noticed the same thing with other sets as well where a random green internal pieces will show up.

Do they do this for a reason?  Are they using colors that don't sell well and trying to get rid of them?  Going for contrast to help you build?

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/why-do-some-sets-contain-parts-of-an-unrelated-colour-that-are-hidden-on-the-fin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some sets contain parts of an unrelated colour that are hidden on the final model?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/why-do-some-sets-contain-parts-of-an-unrelated-colour-that-are-hidden-on-the-fin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Going for contrast to help you build?

This is probably the primary reason most of the time.

[One Eurobricks user once said](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/40452-different-colours-on-the-inside-of-models/&tab=comments#comment-714122) they asked a set designer about it, and they confirmed they do it to makes it easier to follow the instructions:

> I had an opportunity some time ago to talk to a designer at TLG, and he told me that they use other colors to make it easier to follow the instructions and build the model.