# Is there any reason behind fancy bricks in invisible places?

Tags: building, sets, design, city

[image: fancy brick]

In set 60080 there is a blue bick with pretty fancy shape.  There are also hardly visible bricks in other places. Is there any reason? Why are these bricks used? Any official or semi-official explanation?

As far as I remember back when I was young, such pieces were rare, and (if included at all) were used in alternative models proposed on the back of the box. But this set has no such alternative models shown.

Comment: Just my own speculation, but perhaps that piece it's cheaper than the 2x2 and 1x2 plate they could have used.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara this piece indeed looks lightweight. This may well be the case.

Comment: I believe the contrasting colors/shapes are used to make the instructions easier to follow and the pieces easier to find while building...

Comment: Related: [Why do some sets contain parts of an unrelated colour that are hidden on the final model?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/why-do-some-sets-contain-parts-of-an-unrelated-colour-that-are-hidden-on-the-fin)

Comment: @Ambo100 thanks, good catch. I expected something more "interesting" but when I know the answer, it certainly look related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This piece is only two plates high, to have another piece in here you would need to stack two plates, which would

1. make the total pieces count rise, or more expensive
2. might be more difficult to tear down by hand
3. probably less sturdy (with a piece on it acting as a lever stacked plates could pry apart)

Sets designers are under constraints for both piece count, piece prices, 
ease of setup/teardown and sturdyness so I guess this arrangement was decided.

Some examples of other sets with the same kind of piece for the same kind of purpose:

set 4435-1

[image: set 4435-1]

set 60108-1

[image: set 60108-1]

set 60148-1

[image: set 60148-1]

Comment: This makes a perfect sense. And now I'll  have a follow up   question about pieces that  apparently  has no function whatsoever, and add to piece count and assembly difficulty... But I need  to shrink photos  first.