# Why there are "unnecessary" bricks in 60080 LEGO City Space Port?

Tags: sets, city

I [previously asked](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9752/9417) about bricks in invisible places. Now I have second question. There are some bricks that are hardly visible, and in no way contribute to strength of a model. For example lime brick inside space shuttle or red bricks in the launch platform.

Note, as you can see [in instructions](https://lego.com/biassets/bi/6128942.pdf) step 14 - there is nothing on the other side of red brick. It connects only to the long gray technic brick.

Is there any purpose? Are these bricks there to symbolize something? What's the benefit that would justify cost?

[image: lime brick]

[image: red brick]

Comment: Don't know about the lime brick, but the 2nd picture, it's a pin, it holds something together. The designers must have thought it DOES contribute to the structural strength... It's red because that's the common color for such pins...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve when I'll get back home, I will take picture from the bottom side. I'm quite certain that it does not hold anything together, and there were no bricks it could hold left.

Comment: I don't know the set, but in other sets parts like the lime tile, restrict movement of other parts.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve  https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6128942.pdf step 14 - red part is covered with nothing held by it under the plate.

Comment: @Henrik may be, but if you'll look at the instruction https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6158061.pdf step 5 you will see it is held tightly between 2 other brick, and lime brick is only on one side... I don't get it.

Comment: @Molot, I looked up the instructions as well in the mean time, you're correct the pins are not holding anything. My guess would then be that it is supposed to look like it is holding something, i.e. it is decorative... I disagree they are hardly visible, i can see them on the box art. I think they are to symbolize a nut or a stop.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve one  down (maybe), one to go ;)

Comment: The lime piece was probably to try to reduce the movement of the 'towbar' piece (the grey one in the middle), supposed to hold the shuttle on the booster. Maybe at one point during the design the towbar wasnt tightly centered by the two yellow pieces and that centering was done by two pieces like the lime things, but then forgotten to be removed afterwards. The instructions are susceptible to being 'frozen' while not in an optimal state for economical/deadline reasons, so don't look at the instructions as an optimum, but as a starting point for your creativity

Comment: @rienafairefr I don't let rules stop me, thank you :D I just assumed there might be something I'm missing. You are probably right I forgot for a moment that Lego sets are just products with lifestyle. If you would post it as an answer, I'll +1.

Answer (score 5):

I have always assumed that the pieces in question were place holders to simplify assembly.  Their bright color and location help insure proper alignment for less experienced builders. One must realize that the set is marketed to 6-12 year old's. I imagine their testing has proven that such aides are very useful for younger builders.